# How to stop a loop with a condition in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, loops, if-statement, break

I Have this code :

```
- (IBAction)go:(id)sender
{
    int bienPlace = 0;
    int charIndex;
    unichar testChar1, testChar2;

    for (charIndex = 0; charIndex < 3; charIndex++) {
        if (charIndex < 3) {
            resultats.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"4 numbers required"];
            break;
        }

        testChar1 = [saisie.text characterAtIndex:charIndex];
        testChar2 = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", nombreChoisi] characterAtIndex:charIndex];
        if (testChar1 == testChar2) {
            bienPlace++;
        }
    }

    resultats.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%d%@%@", saisie.text, @" good number : ", bienPlace, @"\r", resultats.text];

    if (bienPlace == 4) {
         resultats.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d", @"congratulation, you hack the code : ", nombreChoisi];
    }
    saisie.text = @"";

    [saisie resignFirstResponder];
    saisie.hidden=TRUE;
    saisie.hidden=FALSE;
  }
```

and I want to stop the loop and display a error message when the user enter less 4 characters when press the button named "go".
I wrote this line :

```
if (charIndex < 3) {
     resultats.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"4 numbers required"]
     break;
}
```

but the program display the error message and the loop continue to operate.
A solution ?

Comment: Show us the full context of your `break` statement.  (It's got to be *inside* the loop to be effective, you know.)

Comment: Since your for loop is over `charindex` from 0 to 2, your condition would always be true. Where is your `if` statement relative to your loop?

Comment: The block in the `if` statement is never executed. Also using non-english variable names is a really bad habit. So what is the goal? How should the code work in your opinion?

Comment: I want that the code display a error message when the user enter less 4 characters, reload the loop, when the user enter 4 characters the program work, I don’t want that the user enter more than 4 characters and less 4 characters.

Comment: @Mpk605: But `charIndex` has nothing to do with how many characters your user entered, it's just your loop counter.

Comment: You have a solution ?

Comment: @Mpk605: Checking the length of the text that was entered into your text field seems like an obvious place to start.

Answer (score 2):

That condition is not logically useful in the loop or after it because the loop will only continue while `charIndex is < 3`.  You need to put that if statement before the loop and replace `break;` with `return;`

Comment: If I put that before the loop the user can enter more than 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `return` replace `break`

Because `break` just make current time over, if the condition is true, loop will continue to go.